# JavaScript recursive function breaks when () included in call

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have created a countdown "Pomodoro" timer using JavaScript and JQuery.  The code snippet I am referring to is the following:

```
var time = 1500;
var cycle = "long";
var tracker = 0;
var paused = false;

//Timer countdown function
function countdown(){
    if (!paused) {

        var seconds = ("00" + (time % 60)).slice(-2);

        $("#time").text(Math.floor(time/60) + ":" + seconds);
        $("title").text(Math.floor(time/60) + ":" + seconds);

        if (time > 0){
        time--;
        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
        //Once the time is up, determine cycle, play chime and reset timer.
        } else {
            document.getElementById("bell").play();
            tracker++;

            if (tracker == 7) {
                cycle = "long";
                time = 1500;
                setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            } else if (tracker == 8) {
                time = 1500;
                setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
                tracker = 0;
            } else if (cycle == "short" && tracker < 7) {
                cycle = "long";
                time = 1500;
                setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            } else if (cycle == "long" && tracker < 7) {
                cycle = "short";
                time = 300;
                setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            }
        }  
    } else {
        setTimeout(countdown, 1);
    } 
}
setTimeout(countdown(), 1000);
```

The function calls "setTimeout(countdown, 1000);" located inside the "else" portions of the if statements cause a break in the program when written as follows: "setTimeout(**countdown()**, 1000);", as I believe a function should normally be invoked.  I am completely baffled by this and would very much appreciate if someone was kind enough to offer an explanation.

Question: Why does the program break if "()" is added after the word "countdown"?

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function as a paramter.  So, I'd think that `setTimeout(countdown, 1000);` would be correct. :)

Comment: like @DavinTryon said, it takes a function.  `countdown()` is a statement to execute the function countdown.  if you wanted to do that, you'd need to wrap it inside an anonymous function, ie.  `function(){countdown()}`.  Also, despite the wording of this question, its clearly a duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean by break?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout() with string or (anonymous) function reference? speedwise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506074/settimeout-with-string-or-anonymous-function-reference-speedwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write down `setTimeout(countdown(), 1000);`, basically when that block of code gets evaluated, JS will call `countdown()` inmediatelly. By doing `setTimeout(countdown, 1000);`, you are passing a reference to the function `countdown` as the first argumant, thus, it won't be executed until 1 second later as per the second argument (`1000`).

Comment: No problem, Glad to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax issue. In javascript, you don't pass in the parenthesis with the function, just the name of the function. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter).

Comment: You're not passing names. You want pass the function itself.