# Error in js code

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why this JS code do not work?

It should print time every second:

```
function stampajDatum(){
    var now = new Date();
    var sat = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    document.write(sat + ":" + mins + ":" + sec);
}
setInterval("stampajDatum()", 1000);
```

Comment: Calling `document.write()` after the document has finished loading will reset it, removing all elements that existed. [What are alternatives to document.write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Comment: Also, providing a string to `setInterval()` [is usually considered bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout), for the same reasons as `eval()` – [`setInterval(stampajDatum, 1000)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506074/settimeout-with-string-or-anonymous-function-reference-speedwise).

Comment: Why did you pass in a string into `setInterval`? that is incorrect, the parameter is a function.

Comment: @t0mm13b It's valid – [`setInterval(code, delay)` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) – just not recommended or ideal.

Comment: The function declaration looks valid, but the reality is, it can be anything, even a string..despite the nomenclature declaring convention as `code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function stampajDatum(){
    var now = new Date();
    var sat = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    document.write(sat + ":" + mins + ":" + sec);// the problem is here
    //This writes content to a place after script block
    //if the script is in head then nothing is visible.
    //use something like this:
    //document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = sat + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;
}
setInterval("stampajDatum()", 1000);//This is OK but setInterval(stampajDatum, 1000); is better. 
//Note that there is no () after stampajDatum
```

Answer (score 0):

The first message I'm getting in my console is about that implied eval. Take away the quotes around the function name in `setInterval("stampajDatum()", 1000);` (Making it `setInterval(stampajDatum(), 1000);`)

I don't usually use `setInterval()`, but I know that `setTimeout()` works. Here's an example:

```
function stampajDatum(){
    var now = new Date();
    var sat = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    document.write(sat + ":" + mins + ":" + sec);
    setTimeout(stampajDatum(), 1000);
}
stampajDatum();
```